# Lists vs. NumPy arrays for appending and stacking

Tags: python, list, numpy, stack

I am curious to know if there is a way to stack a NumPy array from having 0 elements to having MxN elements such that in every iteration of a loop, we add a row of size N to the stack.

Below, I have a program for what I was describing, and it does work.

```
import numpy as np

initial_lst = np.linspace(1, 100, 100)
print(initial_lst)

output = np.array([])
i = 0
for arr_part in initial_lst.reshape(10, 10):
    # Insert random intermittent process here
    new_stack = arr_part * 2
    # Stack the array 
    if i==0:
        output = np.append(output, new_stack) # output.shape is (0,) and new_stack.shape is (10,)
        i += 1
    elif i==1:
        output = np.stack((output, new_stack)) # both arrays have shape of (10,)
        i += 1
    else:
        output = np.append(output, [new_stack], axis=0) # output has an ever increasing shape of (10, n)

print(output)
```

This program creates an `np.linspace` from 1-100, reshapes it, multiplies every row of 10 numbers by two, and stacks it onto an output array. This is the output I am getting, which is correct.

```
[[  2.   4.   6.   8.  10.  12.  14.  16.  18.  20.]
 [ 22.  24.  26.  28.  30.  32.  34.  36.  38.  40.]
 [ 42.  44.  46.  48.  50.  52.  54.  56.  58.  60.]
 [ 62.  64.  66.  68.  70.  72.  74.  76.  78.  80.]
 [ 82.  84.  86.  88.  90.  92.  94.  96.  98. 100.]
 [102. 104. 106. 108. 110. 112. 114. 116. 118. 120.]
 [122. 124. 126. 128. 130. 132. 134. 136. 138. 140.]
 [142. 144. 146. 148. 150. 152. 154. 156. 158. 160.]
 [162. 164. 166. 168. 170. 172. 174. 176. 178. 180.]
 [182. 184. 186. 188. 190. 192. 194. 196. 198. 200.]]
```

While it does work, I was curious to see if this could all be done more concisely, similarly to the program below, which does the exact same thing but using normal Python lists.

```
import numpy as np

initial_lst = np.linspace(1, 100, 100)
print(initial_lst)

output = []
i = 0
for arr_part in initial_lst.reshape(10, 10):
    # Insert random intermittent process here
    new_stack = arr_part * 2
    # Stack the array by converting numpy.array to a Python list
    output.append(new_stack.tolist())

print(np.array(output))
```

Duplicating `np.append` lines into other steps results in dimension errors. For example, if I replace the `np.stack` line with this for the time the arrays are both the same size:

```
elif i==1:
    output = np.append(output, [new_stack]) # both arrays have shape of (10,)
    i += 1
```

I get the following error.

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 2 dimension(s)
```

I have also tried using `np.concatenate` in the following way:

```
output = np.concatenate([output, new_stack])
```

However, it just returns me a 1x100 array instead of a 10x10, and specifying `axis=1` gives me dimensional errors.

I can provide more errors if need be, but that's the general idea. My question is the following:

1. Is there a way to get the output I want in as few lines as possible without converting to a Python list? If so, how do they compare in terms of performance?
2. How do list methods compare against NumPy operations for appending and stacking in general?

Comment: `stack` and `append` are just alternate ways of using `np.concatenate`.  `concatenate` joins multiple arrays with matching shapes into one.  But to use it you have to clearly understand arrays shapes.  Your stubling around suggests that isn't clear to you.  BUT none of these is intended for repeated use, not even the poorly named `np.append`.  This has come up many times on SO.  For iterative use, stick with lists.  They are designed to grow.

Comment: To indulge your explorations a bit more.  `np.stack` takes arrays with identical shapes, and joins them on a NEW axis.  Clearly that does not make sense when used repeatedly.  `np.concatenate` takes multiple arrays that match on all but one axis, the joining one.  It can be used repeatedly, but that is slow.   Keep in mind the `np.array([])` makes a (0,) shape array; you can't join that to a (1,10) shaped arrays.  `np.append` is a way of using `concatenate` with just 2 arrays.  Why would anyone want to limit themselves to 2 when `concatenate` takes 10?

Comment: You don't need to `tolist` in `output.append(new_stack.tolist())`.  `np.array` works with a list of arrays.  `np.stack` will also work here.  In any case, build the list of lists or arrays, and do just one array construction at the end.

Comment: I also looked into it more and realized I can initialize an empty array with `np.empty` or `np.zeros` if need be instead of using using `np.array([])`. Otherwise, thanks @hpaulj, those are super helpful! I usually try to avoid lists since they are inefficient when dealing with numerical calculations, but I will definitely look more into lists and NumPy arrays as data structures.

Comment: Yes, you can create `np.empty((0,10))` shaped arrays.  The problem with arrays is that each `concatenate` makes a NEW array, which means each iteration copies larger and larger arrays.  List append just adds a pointer to the list.  An alternative with arrays is to make a large `zeros` array, and do a `arr[i,:]= ...` assignment each time.  Arrays are faster than lists only if you use them as intended.  Trying to imitate list methods with arrays is nearly always slower.

Comment: Editing question to be more generalized as more of a "Lists vs. NumPy arrays for list operations."

Answer (score 1):

`np.concatenate` will work in this way:

```
import numpy as np

initial_lst = np.linspace(1, 100, 100)
print(initial_lst)

output = np.zeros((1,10))

for arr_part in initial_lst.reshape(10, 10):
    # Insert random intermittent process here
    #print(arr_part)
    new_stack = arr_part * 2
    # Stack the array by converting numpy.array to a Python list
    if not output.any():
       output = new_stack[None,:]
       continue
    output = np.concatenate((output,new_stack[None,:]),axis=0)

print(output)
```

But this is slow. Observe that you are working on 1D array slices of reshaped `initial_lst` in each iteration. So efficient approach could be using `np.apply_along_axis` as follows:

```
output= np.apply_along_axis(lambda x:x*2, 1,initial_lst.reshape(10,10))
print(output)
```

Comment: In my experience `apply_along_axis` doesn't help with speed (compared to straightforward list comprehension.  For higher numbers of dimensions it does a nice job of hiding nested iterations.

Comment: From some quick runs on your latter code block, I found that using my second method of appending each row to a list (minus the `tolist()` command that I add, which is redundant) is faster than using `apply_along_axis` by about 0.15 ms on my machine. Since the intermittent process that I will eventually be using this for is more complicated than just `x*2`, I'll stick with the list methodology.